# storing data in hdfs instead of a message queue

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am trying to change the method data is processed in an application. Data is first received from database and stored in message queue. I want the data to be put in hdfs directly. I do not want data to write into  file and move to hdfs. From HDFS I will process data and put result into hdfs. Instead of giving copy command to hdfs, can I write from Java program the data to HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of reason why your approach is not advisible.

1. Writing each of the message to the hdfs will be a costly operation.
2. You can't write a message directly to hdfs, it has to be written to a file first and that needs to be put into hdfs.
3. Approach 2, would generate lot of small sized files in hdfs, increasing burden on name node to track each chunk of that file.

I would suggest, set a threshold for the messaging queue, once that threshold is reached move all the messages to a file and then to hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options depending on your current setup.

1. Sqoop - http://sqoop.apache.org/ - Designed for bulk transferring between structured data stores (relational databases) and HDFS.  Without knowing more about your setup, this may or may not work for you.
2. Apache Spark - https://spark.apache.org/ - Can read from a variety of sources including ZeroMQ, Kafka, HDFS, etc.  It also supports custom inputs (sources).  You could perhaps do any processing of the data you need in a streaming fashion from the queue and output directly to HDFS.  Again, this depends on your setup.
3. Apache Kafka / MapReduce - http://kafka.apache.org/ - This may not be an option, but using Apache Kafka as your 'queue' would allow you to run MapReduce against it, directly outputting to HDFS.
4. WebHDFS / HTTPfs - https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html - REST interface to HDFS.  You could combine whatever you extract from the database with and POST data to HDFS directly.  This does have some caveats though and I wouldn't recommend it without caution.

Options 2 and 3 don't seem to be exactly what you're looking for, but may be a compromise.